# Shrink both height and width of a div by scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onscroll

Is it possible to shrink both the height and the width of a div simultaneously while scrolling down a page? For example, as the user scrolls down, the div size goes from 400px by 400px to 200px by 200px while staying in the center of the page? I know it's possible to shrink the height OR the width using jQuery, but I haven't seen anything on shrinking both.

Comment: yes just use the scroll event to catch the document's position using scrollTop and set the width of your div using $(div).width and the same for the height/ use .css() .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height and width, decrement both, and then reapply the new values inside of a scroll event.

```
var divToChange = $('#sizeShifter');
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var divHeight = divToChange.height();
    var divWidth = divToChange.width();
    divHeight-=5;
    divWidth-=5;
    divToChange.css({width:divWidth, height:divHeight});
});
```

You can also reverse this effect when the user scrolls up.  This is a little more involved, but here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jpcg/4/) to get you started.

Comment: I added a bunch of line breaks to see what it looks like when scrolling, and it works pretty well! But I noticed when you scroll back up, it doesn't always revert to 400px by 400px. Could it be that
`divHeight-=5;
divWidth-=5;
` 


do not reset when you scroll back up to the top of the page?

Comment: @superquestion It probably depends on how fast you scroll.  The faster you scroll, the fewer times the function gets called.  Thus, if you scrolled down slow and up fast, you would end up with a smaller div.  If you wanted the size to always revert, you would need to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/hmu3c/1/  This code sets the height and width based on the distance from the top.  So it will always be the same size at the top.

Comment: Why is that when an image is used with the same id, that the margin rules no longer apply? (I am trying to get this to be centered horizontally and vertically in the page so I figured seeing why the margin rules no longer applied was a good place to start.) Also, I'm pretty sure there is a way to stop the image from shrinking once it gets to a certain size, and once it is at that size, the image will no longer be fixed in the center of the viewport(I'm pretty sure this is getting in to parallax kind of stuff).
http://jsfiddle.net/hmu3c/1/

Comment: @superquestion You certainly could.  Here is a quick example that roughly approximates what you described. http://jsfiddle.net/hmu3c/8/

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but what is the purpose of the `var lastScroll = 0;` declaration?

Comment: That is only called when the script first runs.  This declaration sets the original scrolling position to 0, which is the top of the page.  This is just so that we have a value to compare the first reading to.