# Change div scale on scroll

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reduce the scale of a div to .7 as well as the opacity to .5 when the user scrolls down on a site.

I have found a few examples of this question on here but none that apply 2 effects and many that do not have successful answers.

The name of the main div which contains the background image is

.home-hero-effect .background-wrapper (I am using visual composer)

I tried the below code as a starting point but it made no change at all and I am unsure how to add the opacity effect to it.

The origin being here 
[Shrink both height and width of a div by scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070882/shrink-both-height-and-width-of-a-div-by-scrolling?rq=1)

```
var divToChange = $('.home-hero-effect.background-wrapper');
var lastScroll = 0;
$(document).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScroll){
        var divHeight = divToChange.height();
        var divWidth = divToChange.width();
        divHeight-=5;
        divWidth-=5;
        divToChange.css({'width':divWidth, 'height':divHeight});
    } 
    else {
        var divHeight = divToChange.height();
        var divWidth = divToChange.width();
        divHeight+=5;
        divWidth+=5;
        divToChange.css({'width':divWidth, 'height':divHeight});
    }
    lastScroll = st;
});
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the correct syntax for the jquery .css command:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp
  In particular, you need "width" and "height" in quotes, otherwise they both will be interpreted as variables instead of text.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what to make of that - i have just taken this from the other Stack Overflow question

Comment: divToChange.css({"width":divWidth, "height":divHeight, "opacity":someVariable});

Comment: @Zizzyzizzy - Thanks for your reply. I have edited the code in the original question to reflect your suggestion but unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: @Mr Toad can you point which part that does not work, if there are an error can you add the error to your question?